# How to merge many commits into one in github repository

Tags: git, github

I have a github repository that shows too many commits and i want to squash them into one.
Is there a way to make these commits look like my current local repo exactly?

Comment: What does it mean "shows too many commits"?  Having *many commits* is not bad, having them **too large** and **too small** is.

Comment: I think you are right. I should just keep them as such.

Comment: Can negative voter tell why it is down-voted ?

Comment: I have some commits that are wrong implementation and i want to remove them.

Comment: If it is on GitHub (as opposed to be only in your private repository before push), then it is too late.  You can use tools such as interactive rebase or filter-branch to clean up history (remove commits with bugs, squash fixes, perhaps reorder and split commit), but you should have done it before *publishing* history.  Changing published history inconveniences all developers who works from your repository.

Answer (score 2):

You can squash commits on your local repo by using interactive rebase. After that you can use force push.

`git push -f`

But be careful if there are anybody else also working on your github repo, as you might lose commits. I usually only force push to repos/branches where I'm the only one commiting to it. Also by default git pushes all branches. So it's a good idea to specify what branch you want to push i.e.

`git push -f origin master`

I've set up my git to only push the current branch to avoid messing up the remote repo by a mistake.

`git config --global push.default current`