# git rebase is not working

Tags: git, github

I made some commits in my local repo and have pushed them to the online repo too.

Then i realized that there are to many commits and i want to squash them into little. Preferably from `second last one` to `first one`. i.e. keeping current commit and squashing all other my commits.

when i do

```
 git rebase -i origin/branch_name
```

Window with `noop` pops up. I do not see any `pick`. What should i do ?

Comment: you can't squash pushed commits

Comment: I asked it here can you tell if its right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651000/how-to-merge-many-commits-into-one-in-github-repository

Comment: technically, you can if you have the rights on your distant repo. but that's really a bad practice

Comment: Yaa but, thats just my branch and its good for learning. Sometimes tough times call for tough decisions.

Answer (score 4):

When I get the `noop` message, it usually means the branch used in the argument of `git rebase -i` is ahead of checked out branch.

```sh
git log A..B
# prints the commits between A's head and B's head

git log B..A
# prints nothing

git status
# On branch A

git rebase -i B
# got 'noop' because there are no commits in the log above
```

In this case, it helps to swap the two affected branches.

```
git checkout B
git rebase -i A
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument for the rebase command is the range of commits you want to squash. In your case, probably something like :

```
git rebase -i <sha-1 for first commit>..HEAD^
```

(HEAD^ being the parent commit to the head of your branch).

Then, you replace the `pick` commands in the interactive script by `squash`